# Jquery UI Sortable - Get the item being sorted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-plugins, this

When using Jquery UI Sortable (which is great by the way) how do you get the item that is currently being sorted.

When you use `$(this);` it return the actual sortable list, not the current sorted item.

I want to do fancy-pants things with the widget when the user is dragging it around. E.g. Animate it when dragging between two lists.

So how do I get the current item being sorted?

There a little code below just to explain a little more...

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable_1").sortable({
        start : function(event, ui){ 
            //get current element being sorted
        },
        stop : function(event, ui){ 
            //get current element being sorted
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As far as I'm aware `ui` in your `start: function(event, ui)` is the current element being sorted.

As pointed out in the comments `ui.item` is the current element.

Comment: Cheers.

It's ui.item but ui is close enough. Have a tick.

Comment: How we then use ui.item along with jQuery for example removing a class from it?
this does not work `ui.item.removeClass("invisible");` for me

Comment: @limitcracker if you're still looking I think it would be `$(ui.item).removeClass("invisible");`

Comment: I would add that `ui.item` returns an object, so if you really want the element you should use `ui.item[0]`. This way you can get a normal JS element. Now you could do for example 'ui.item[0].classList.add("yourClass")`.